# change exsisiting radio button into a <a href>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, hyperlink

my existing code generates a random webpage from a predetermined list after clicking on a radio button. I want to remove the radio button and create a "a href" in my nav bar to create the same effect.

Here is my current code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function randomlinks(){
 var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*9)
 var links=new Array()
 links[0]="http://www.javascriptkit.com"
 links[1]="http://www.dynamicdrive.com"
 links[2]="http://www.cssdrive.com"
 links[3]="http://www.codingforums.com"
 links[4]="http://www.news.com"
 links[5]="http://www.gamespot.com"
 links[6]="http://www.msnbc.com"
 links[7]="http://www.cnn.com"
 links[8]="http://news.bbc.co.uk"
 links[9]="http://www.news.com.au"

 window.location=links[myrandom]
 }
 </script>
```

Radio Button

```
 <form>
 <input type="button" value="random link!" onClick="randomlinks()">
 </form>
```

How do I remove the radio button "form" and move the functionality of into a "a href" attribute. The a "a href" link will be used in a simple nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like to put JS directly in an anchor's `href` attribute, I guess due to old habits of providing a valid URL in the `href` so that the user still gets a working page even if they've disabled JavaScript, and putting the JS in an `onclick` attribute.

Actually I don't really like to include inline event attributes either, but the following will work:

```
<a href="#" onclick="randomlinks(); return false;>Random Link!</a>
```

(The `return false;` prevents default link behaviour.)